# How can I track down what is causing `go build` to take a long time?

Tags: go

Running it with -v does not really tell me what the problem is. It takes about 20s before printing even a single line.

Running it under `strace` outputs a lot of noise, and `strace` does not run on Mac OS.

Removing dependencies to see if they are the problem would be a ridiculous amount of work.

Comment: `-x` shows all commands being executed

Comment: @jimB I think that's the answer. Would you like to post it as an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `-x` flag to show all commands being executed:

https://godocs.io/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_packages_and_dependencies